# Crop video that has been taken the vertical way on iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, video-editing

I frequently capture video holding my phone as usual, which means vertically. 
But when I want to watch it on a computer screen, I would like to have it full screen - even if it means loosing the top and bottom of the scene.

I'm sure there a lot of softwarz that do this on a mac but I wanted to be able to do it directlty in my picture library of my phone.

Is there an app that makes it ? Or is this an hiddent trick to do it with the Photo App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no not really, you could find a third party app, doing this on a comp is easy however! why not use it in landscape to begin with? it drives me crazy when people film in portrait, why? because almost every screen you watch your media on is "landscape"

Comment: It also drived me crazy until I started to film myself. We're just accustomed to hold the device this way, so you don't realize it immediatly. Anyway : Do you have the name of a easy app that does it?

Comment: not really i did google it quickly last night, no good results, you could do it on your comp, more easily, HOWEVER i strongly sudgest that you just make yourself film in landcarpe, you are litterly wasting pixels and resolution quality like this... think like this. always use the volume up button to shoot, this way you make yourself film in landscape, kinda...

thats mine, and any logical persons advice!

Comment: I've found an App called Video Swivel who does the trick. Thanks for your advice ;-)

Comment: no problem thanks for telling me the name of the app